# React Native - App is Crashing when opening Tabs

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-vector-icons

My App always crashes in Android Emulator.

Every time I navigate my App into Main Tabs my App Crashes with an error.
I think this is not caused of the React Native Navigation, I think because of the React Native Vector Icons because in Android it requires to Add Icon for the Tabs. This error just suddenly appear without changing any of my codes.

This is the error from React Native Debugger:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Iterator value v is not an entry object
>   at new Map (native)
>   at file:///D:/Downloads/rn-debugger-windows-ia32/resources/app.asar/js/bundle.js:9:8044
>   at anonymous

These are my Dependencies:

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.6",
"react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
"react-native-navigation": "^1.1.493",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.1"
```

Feel free to ask for my codes and any questions. Thank you!

Comment: This is probably an issue with React-Native-Debugger. Are you using `react-native-debugger` as a stand alone app for debugging your react native app?

Comment: @LordKiz Actually the error appears even I'm not using React Native Debugger

Comment: Based on this PR https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/pull/307 , I think this issue was solved. Try upgrading the standalone react native debugger to the latest, clean your project and rerun.

Comment: Okay, will try it.

Comment: How to upgrade my current React Native Debugger? Or should i download a new one?

Comment: remove the old one and download the latest

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error happens when debugging via RND. If this is your case try the following:

1. Try to close and open debugger again. For some reason it fixes the situation sometimes.
2. If your debugger`s version is out of date try to update it.
3. Finally the step that usually works if the previous didn`t: reinstall `react-native-debugger` and clean your cache (`npm start -- --reset-cache`).

To reinstall RND (`OS`): `brew cask reinstall react-native-debugger`.
For `windows` use standard procedure of deleting (via Control Panel) and then installing RND again.